# on the fly generation with Dataset api tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a function which produces feature and target tensors.  E.g.

```
x,t = myfunc() ##x,t tensors
```

How can I integrate this with TensorFlow's dataset API for continuous training?  Ideally I would like to use dataset to set things like batch, transformations.

Edit for clarification: The problem being I would like to not just put x and t in my graph but make a dataset from them so that I can use the same dataset processing that I have implemented for (normal) finite datasets I can load into memory and feed into the same graph using an initializable iterator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `x` and `t` are `tf.Tensor` objects, and `my_func()` builds a TensorFlow graph, you may be able to use the following approach with `Dataset.map():

```
# Creates an infinite dataset with a dummy value. You can make this finite by
# specifying an explicit number of elements to `repeat()`.
dummy_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(0).repeat(None)

# Evaluates `my_func` once for each element in `dummy_dataset`.
dataset = dummy_dataset.map(lambda _: my_func())
```

Comment: If I want to do the computation of my_func() on the gpu device by default, would I put the "with tf.device('/device:GPU:1'):" wrapper on the first, second, or both of the lines you suggested?  This may or may not make a difference but "my_func()" in my case is actually a method of another class (i.e. "my_class.my_func()" is what I would actually use in your code) -- so do I also have to use "with tf.device('/device:GPU:1'):" when instantiating the class?

Answer (score 1):

If x and t are tensors, you can create a dataset by calling `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors` or `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` (documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensor_slices)).

The difference between them is that `from_tensors` combines the input tensors into a single element in the dataset. `from_tensor_slices` creates a dataset with one element for each slice.

Comment: If I use "from_tensors" and then batch the dataset, will it call myfunc multiple times?  I don't want it just to repeat the same tensor multiple times, if that makes sense?

Comment: No, I don't think "from_tensors" will call myfunc multiple times. If you'd like to create a dataset from a generator function, you can call Dataset.from_generator.

Comment: right, but Dataset.from_generator does not accept generators that create *tensor* objects

Comment: Are you saying you want to create a dataset whose tensors will change every time you call myfunc? If so, you could create one dataset and then concatenate more data as it becomes available.

Comment: No, I would like to use something like from_generator, but slightly different.  I have two tensors, x and t, that each time they are called in a graph they evaluate to new training data.  You might think of them like x = tf.random_uniform(args), t = tf.random_uniform(args).  Does that make sense?

Comment: The problem being I would like to not just put x and t in my graph but make a dataset from them so that I can use the same dataset processing that I have implemented for (normal) finite datasets I can load into memory and feed into the same graph using an initializable iterator.