# training tensorflow data API with procedural on-the-fly data generation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318734/on-the-fly-generation-with-dataset-api-tensorflow) one, in that I would like to generate batches of training data on the fly. I have a function `get_random_batch(batch_size, input_path, target_path, **other_kwargs)` which returns `inputs` and `targets`, but it is a pure vanilla python / numpy function, not tensorflow. So it returns numpy arrays, not tensors. (The function is quite a large complex one with some 3rd party libs. To port it to tensorflow is not very feasible. To preprocess everything is also not feasible as the data is huge, and I don't have the space to store it all preprocessed! In fact I don't even train a single epoch, I just take random selections for hundreds of thousands of iterations).

For a few years I've been using tensorflow's low level training API: generate a batch of input-target pairs, run forward pass with feed (into placeholders) and fetch, calculate loss, apply gradients, repeat etc.

Now I finally would like to try out the newer data API (so that I can use the Keras API for building the model and 'fitting' etc), but I can't figure out how to migrate. All of the documentation I've seen assumes that the data loading and preprocessing is part of the graph, and the output of the dataset are already tensors.

--

**Update**: Ok this seems to work with **tf.data.Dataset.from_generator**

```
compile_kwargs = dict(
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(3e-4),
    loss = 'mse',
    metrics = ['accuracy', 'mse']
)

def prepare_data():
    x,t = get_random_training_pair() # this returns one training pair (each np.float32 ndarrays)
    yield (x, t)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(prepare_data, (tf.float32, tf.float32))
dataset = dataset.batch(128).repeat()
model = build_keras_model()
model.compile(**compile_kwargs)
model.summary()
model.fit(dataset, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=100, shuffle=False)
```

Comment: if you are looking to just replace the placeholders in your graph with iterators, you could probably define the graph and use the method suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375518/10111931) to take input data from your numpy function?

Comment: thanks for the link @kvish, in this case i'm trying out the keras API instead of building the graph myself - I'm trying to reduce boilerplate code. So I think all of that would actually increase the code I need to write!

Comment: If I have understood that clearly, you're looking for a way to incorporate your python function which generates random data with the tf data api so that you can feed the dataset to keras for your training?

Comment: in that case, you can use [from_generator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) method with the data api if you can write a wrapper to define your python process as a generator. Is there anything particular you are looking to do here with Keras

Comment: @kvish thx, generator approach looks promising. I'm just confused what exactly the generator should return, should it yield a single random training pair? (or a batch?). P.S. I'm looking into keras because I have a simple MLP, and I can potentially replace a few 100 lines of code (graph build+train+valid loop), with just 5-10 lines! (& more likely to be bug free). and yes that's exactly what i'm trying to do (re your prev comment).

Comment: the regular use case for a tf data pipeline is to create a tuple (data, label) so that you can feed such a dataset directly to keras by just invoking an iterator. You can batch the data with the [batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch) method which could be convenient if you want to shuffle your data before you group it. Check out [importing data guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets), and [keras guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras).

Comment: yup i think I got it working. see new code. thanks for your help.

Comment: thats great! You can also use the [prefetch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#prefetch) function to speed up your pipeline. Refer to the [performance guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/overview) for more suggestions :)